# Error when deploying cakephp application on ubuntu

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp

Good morning,

I’m currently using Cakephp 3 version to develop an application. It should be online on an Ubuntu server and through the subdomain: http://etraining.minmap.cm

To do this, I configured a virtualHost, with the content :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName etraining.minmap.cm
    ServerAlias www.etraining.minmap.cm
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/etraining.minmap.cm/public_html/webroot
    
    <Directory /var/www/etraining.minmap.cm/public_html/webroot>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The content of the .htaccess located at the application folder is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

The content of the .htaccess located at webroot directory is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have followed all the configuration steps outlined in the official documentation.
mod_rewrite is enabled, mbstring and intl extensions are also enabled

But, I have 500 Internal Server Error:

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

This is the error reported in my Apache error.log:

[image: Apache error]

I don’t know if I misconfigured Apache, my `.htaccess` files, and/or the `config/app.php`?

Comment: Please do a search for the error found in the apache logs, this is a very popular problem: **https://www.google.com/search?q=request+exceeded+the+limit+of+10+internal+redirects+due+to+probable+configuration+error+site:stackoverflow.com**. Also to get more details enable `LogLevel debug` as the message suggests.

Comment: The most important bit of information in your question and you've linked to an externally hosted image - why not simply copy/paste the error into your question?

Comment: "The content of the .htaccess located at the application folder is:" - Where's the "application folder"? This doesn't seem necessary, given the vHost config you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable apache re-write module. It will work

1. "sudo a2enmod rewrite"
2. "sudo service apache2 restart"

Comment: They wouldn't be getting a "rewrite-loop" (500 error) - details in the linked screenshot - if mod_rewrite wasn't already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Update .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you provide more explanation... these directives make a fundamental change to how the application is called, which isn't mentioned in the question?